# Parsing time offset in Go using time package

Tags: go, time

I am trying to use Time package in Go to extract the time details as under. I have been able to successfully parse values such as year, month, date, hour, minutes and seconds. Unfortunately, when I try to use Zone to extract offset, I seem to be getting an incorrect offset.

When I tried to view my Time object, I see two entries for offset, not sure what am I doing incorrectly.

```
 serverTime := "2021-10-31T22:17:03.996-0700"
    fmt.Println("Server time is: ", serverTime)
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999-0700", serverTime)
    zone, offset := t.Zone()
    fmt.Println("Printing time object: ",t)
    fmt.Println("Year", t.Year())
    fmt.Println("Month", t.Month().String())
    fmt.Println("Date", t.Day())
    fmt.Println("Hour", t.Hour())
    fmt.Println("Minutes", t.Minute())
    fmt.Println("Seconds",t.Second())

    fmt.Println("Zone:", zone)
    fmt.Println("Offset", offset)
```

The output that is see for offset is:
Offset -25200
and I expect it to be -0700

Here is the link to [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8zFqNcMD3E1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [func(Time) Zone](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Zone) returns the second argument `offset` which is the seconds east of UTC. So your offset of `-0700` is returned as `-25200` which is - (7 * 60 * 60)